# Quiero darle a unas variables el valor de elementos de una tabla sql en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Soy nuevo en Python y estoy intentando crear una aplicación TPV, pero me he quedado en blanco, ya que no se como resolver esto.

Quiero que las variables `nombre` y `precio` tengan el valor de la tabla `productos` y guardarlas en otra tabla `comanda` junto con otras variables `input`.

Lo que no se es como lograr que los valores se puedan usar como variable fuera del `if`, que por otro lado al intentar poner el `cursor.execute` dentro del `if` no realiza ninguna acción en la tabla.

Aquí tenéis el código:

```
def Caja():

    import os,sys,sqlite3
    import time
    t = time.localtime()
    linea_ticket=[] 
    mesa=input("introduzca el numero de mesa:  ")
    print ("asctime : ",time.asctime(t))
    con = sqlite3.connect('Articulos.s3db')
    cursor=con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from productos")
    print("Listado de productos")
    for productos in cursor:
        product='\t'+str(productos[0])+str(productos[1])+str(productos[2])+'\t'
        print(str(product))
    unidades=input("introduzca el numero de unidades a comandar")
    id=input("introduzca el id del producto a comandar")
    for productos in product:
        if int(productos[0]==int(id)):
            nombre=productos[1]
            precio=productos[2]
            encontrado=True
            linea_ticket.append(nombre, precio)
            break   

    print(linea_ticket)
    estado=1

    nombre=linea_ticket[1]
    precio=linea_ticket[2]
    cursor.execute("insert into Comanda(Articulo, Precio, Unidades, Mesa, Estado) values ('"+nombre+"', '"+precio+"', '"+unidades+"', '"+mesa+"', '"+estado+"' )")

    con.commit()
    con.close()

    Caja()
```

Gracias por adelantado, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, que llevo un par de días con esto.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias almacenar las filas de los productos en una lista o en un diccionario (con `id` como clave) y buscar los productos en el. No obstante, si usas una base de datos obtén los datos de ella directamente. No tiene mucho sentido crear un duplicado de la tabla en una variable, además de ser muy ineficiente si la tabla llega aser extensa.

Cuando se ingrese una id simplemente haz una consulta a la tabla `productos` de la bd para que te retorne su nombre y su precio.

Vamos a verlo con el código y con un ejemplo totalmente reproducible. Primero creamos una base de datos con las dos tablas necesarias y una pequeña lista de productos:

```
import sqlite3


with sqlite3.connect('Articulos.s3db') as con:
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE productos (id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                                              nombre text NOT NULL,
                                              precio float NOT NULL)''')
    lista = ((1, "Agua",     0.90), 
             (2, "Tostadas", 1.50), 
             (3, "Cafe",     1.00), 
             (4, "Pizza",    2.50))

    for producto in lista:        
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO productos (id, nombre, precio) VALUES (?,?,?)",
                      producto)

    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE Comanda (Articulo text,
                                            Precio float,
                                            Unidades integer,
                                            Mesa integer,
                                            Estado integer)''')
```

Ahora que tenemos la base de datos vamos con tu código:

```
import sqlite3

def caja():
    t = time.localtime()
    linea_ticket = [] 
    mesa = input("Introduzca el numero de mesa:  ")
    print ("asctime : ", time.asctime(t))

    # Imprimimos todos los productos tabulados con ayuda de str.format
    with sqlite3.connect('Articulos.s3db') as con:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select * from productos")
        print("Listado de productos:")
        print("{:>5}   {:>15}   {:>6}".format("id", "Nombre",  "Precio"))
        for producto in cursor:
            print("{:>5}   {:>15}   {:>6.2f}".format(*producto))

        estado = 1    
        unidades = int(input("Introduzca el numero de unidades a comandar: "))
        id = int(input("Introduzca el id del producto a comandar: "))

        # Buscamos el producto con esa id en la db
        cursor.execute("SELECT nombre, precio FROM productos WHERE id=:id", {"id": id})        
        con.commit()
        producto = cursor.fetchone()
        if producto:
            nombre,  precio = producto
            cursor.execute("insert into Comanda(Articulo, Precio, Unidades, Mesa, Estado) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
                           ((nombre, precio, unidades, mesa, estado)))
            linea_ticket.append((nombre, precio))
        else:
            print("Producto no encontrado")
```

Las diferencias con respecto a tu código son:

- Uso de la sentencia `with` para usar el  protocolo de manejador de contexto. Esto asegura que tu cursor aplica los cambios y que tu conexión es cerrada de forma automática. No es necesario, puedes cerrarla al terminar tu mismo con `close()`, yo suelo usarlo ya que soy tendente a olvidarme de cerrar después de unas cuantas línes de código :(
- Se usa `format` para formatear la salida en forma de tabla de la lista de productos, es muy simple (se pueden crear salidas más elaboradas) pero se ve mucho mejor.
- El cambio importante y relevante es que la id se consulta al atabla directamente con:

  ```
  cursor.execute("SELECT nombre, precio FROM productos WHERE id=:id", {"id": id})
  ```

  Retornará una tupla con el nombre y el precio del producto asociado a esa id, en caso de no existir retorna `None`.

---

Un ejemplo de ejecución real:

```
>>> caja()

Introduzca el numero de mesa:  4
asctime :  Sat Sep 16 15:34:09 2017
Listado de productos:
   id            Nombre   Precio
    1              Agua     0.90
    2          Tostadas     1.50
    3              Cafe     1.00
    4             Pizza     2.50
Introduzca el numero de unidades a comandar: 2
Introduzca el id del producto a comandar: 3
```

Podemos comprobar que el producto se ha añadido a la tabla `Comanda`:

```
>>> with sqlite3.connect('Articulos.s3db') as con:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select * from Comanda")
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)

('Cafe', 1.0, 2, 4, 1)
```

> Nota: los `import` se deberían realizar en las primeras líneas del script (despueś de las dos primeras si se usan para ["Shebang"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang)), no dentro de la función. Por otro lado, si seguimos los consejos de PEP-8 deberían estar cada uno en una linea diferente.